# When to use Null vs. N/A in columns?

Tags: database, database-design, database-schema

Suppose you have 2 columns in a table: FixedSalary and HourlyRate. The value for one of these columns is always going to be missing because an employee cannot be paid both a fixed salary and an hourly rate.

Now, suppose I have another table HairColor column. You're updating a row for a patient who is bald. The value will be missing.

For both examples, we can either use a Null value or something like "N/A" or "Not applicable". I was wondering, is there a best (database design) practice regarding these situations, where there is a clearly lack of value, but that lack of value is for a very clear logical reason?

Comment: Null means "there is no answer", NA means "we know the answer, and it's not applicable".  If N/A is a possibility, I would suggest defining a boolean column.  However, in the case of hair color, "Bald" is certainly a valid color.

Comment: Ask yourself first why you would put FixedSalary and HourlyRate into the same table when one or other them is always inapplicable. The alternative would be to have distinct tables for the two subtypes of employee. Attributes applicable to every employee would go in one common table. Attributes applicable only to certain types of employee would go into the specific subtype table.

Comment: Good comment, @sqlvogel.  I direct people to [tag:class-table-inheritance].

Comment: BTW NULL is not a value.

Answer (score 4):

As usual, it depends.  Here, it depends on what message you want conveyed between the application that writes the data, and the application that reads it.

NULL normally conveys the message "there is no value at this location".  That's often all the reader needs to know.  In particular,   in the case of hourly versus salaried, a well formed reader app should not be particularly surprised that one of them is missing, in every instance.

A special value to indicate "not applicable" is only really needed when the reader of the data is expected to behave one way when the data is missing because it's not applicable, and a different way when it's missing for a different reason, like a user omission on an input form.  This could be the case for hair color, but it depends on your case.

The best practice is to analyze your case, and design accordingly.

Answer (score 2):

The best practice is the `Null` value

**EDIT**

Null value is preferable, because that allows the database engine and client programs to automatically handle this value properly, without writing custom code for that. (think about for example sorting values)

Comment: Your preference may be null. Many, many people will disagree about it being "best practice".

Comment: I think we expect substantiation for an answer... reasoning for your conclusion, or at least a link to some relatively authoritative source stating this.

Answer (score 0):

As per my database knowledge, `Null` or `null` is a keyword. Where as `Not Applicable` or `N/A` is user defined. So it all depends on how you like to parse the result set.

What would you prefer, `rs.getString(COLUMN_NAME);` returning `null` or `N/A`.

According to me, `null` would be nice, because, it is easy to check for `!= null`.

Comment: `!= null` is a meaningless expression in SQL, which is probably what most readers are thinking about. Comparisons involving any `null` always return `unknown`, not a boolean, including `!=`. Special operators need to be used to check whether or not something is `null` and get a non-`unknown`, boolean result.